# How to do a NHibernate many-to-one/one-to-many foreign key in case of navigation property name different from property type?

Tags: c#, .net, nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate

I'm using NHibernate/FluentNhibernate with AutoMapping configuration and I'm having troubles with foreign keys of some relationships. Especially those where the navigation property name is different from the the name of the type it is pointing to :

```
public class Country       
{
    public virtual string Code { get; set; }

    public virtual string Name { get; set; }

    public virtual Currency DefaultCurrency { get; set; }
}

public class Currency
{
    public virtual string Code { get; set; }

    public virtual decimal Rate { get; set; }

    public virtual IList<Country> Countries { get; set; }     
}
```

In the case of Country entity where the name of navigation property `DefaultCurrency` is different from the name `Currency` type. The automapping of NHibernate will guess that the Country table will have the following foreign key:

- `DefaultCurrency_id`: corresponding to the relation of `Country.Currency`
- `Currency_id`: corresponding to the relation of `Currency.Countries`

How to tell to the automapping that the relation `Currency.Countries` can be expressed with `DefaultCurrency_id` key, resulting to one key foreign only for the Country table:

- `DefaultCurrency_id`: corresponding to the relation of `Country.Currency` and `Currency.Countries`

Comment: Can you post your `Fluent` mapping?

Answer (score 1):

You can specify any column name you want in the mapping.

For references:

```
References(x => x.Foo, "MyFooId")
```

For has-many:

```
HasMany(x => x.Foos)
    .KeyColumn("MyFooId")
```

For many-to-many:

```
HasManyToMany(x => x.Foos)
    .ChildKeyColumn("MyFooId")
    .ParentKeyColumn("MyFooId")
```

You can also use conventions, e.g.:

```
public class HasManyConventions : IHasManyConvention
{
    public void Apply(IOneToManyCollectionInstance target)
    {
        target.Key.Column(target.EntityType.Name + "Id");
    }
}
```